# Visual Studio 2010 linking libraries and include paths for multiple projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a visual studio 2010 project where I use glew, glut and glm. I have successfully linked all the libraries and dll for the project.

Question is how do I do it once and when I create new project all the linked , libraries and paths linked from past project are still there.

So I dont have to do this all again.

Thank you.

Comment: [How to: Create Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own project templates.

1. Create empty project with all your libraries linked.
2. File -> Export Template
3. Select "Project Template", then choose template name and icons.
4. Check if "Automatically import the template into Visual Studio" checked.
5. Now you can create projects with your template.

Comment: Hi Thank you. On visual studio 2010 when I go to file I can not seem to see the export template option. Could it be hidden or do I have to download some sort of template wizard etc.

Comment: Hi, you can install [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24/) official extension. Use "Export Template as VSIX..." in File menu to export your template.

Comment: Hi Just downloaded the extension. Seems to only accept. Supported Products : 
06/04/2014 17:46:57 -   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
06/04/2014 17:46:57 -    Version : [10.0]
06/04/2014 17:46:57 -   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
06/04/2014 17:46:57 -    Version : [10.0]
06/04/2014 17:46:57 -   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
06/04/2014 17:46:57 -    Version : [10.0] I have visual studio 2010.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2010 Express? I think it doesn't work with this version.

Comment: Yeah I have visual studio 2010 express. Is they a work around.